# Shape File Editing Libraries

Tags: python, .net, automation, shapefile, arcpy

I need to automate correction of errors by removing duplicate polygon nodes in some ESRI shapefiles I just received. I am however stumped as to how to use ArcPy to achieve this.

My search for libraries to do this also yielded few results. The best one ([Python Shape File Library](http://code.google.com/p/pyshp)) is able to edit the shapefiles but the errors still persist.

Are there any freely available libraries I can use for this task?
If not, how can I use ArcPy to automate the process?

I prefer libraries in .NET (C# or VB.NET) or Python.

Comment: What is it about PyShp that's allowing the errors to remain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Duplicate polygon nodes"

Don't know what a node is (except in the old coverage days), but I assume you mean duplicate points in the polygon rings. If you have arcpy, then you have ArcGIS.  Why don't you use the Repair Geometry toolbox tool?  That will fix duplicate points on inner or outer rings of polygons and a bunch of other geometry errors, too.

If you meant to say duplicate polygons, then use the Find Identical tool, if you have that license level.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I successfully repaired the shape files using the Repair Geometry tool. After merging them, I used the Delete Identical tool to find and delete duplicate polygons.